# How to dynamically pass hyperlink URL to a label in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a label on which I want to ensure that when user clicks the label, it opens a hyperlink attached with it in a webview.

Label and its hyperlink are fetched from an SQLite database.

Can you please let me know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Give IBAction on your custome button

 -(IBAction) goToLink
 {
        NSString *Links_name = @"Your link";
        NSLog(@"Link : %@",Links_name);
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:Links_name]]; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't since you can't pass an action event with Label.

So, for this you need to use Custom Button

or either the TextView using detection property of TextView.

USing of Custom Button is much easy then using TextView.

hope that will work... :)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Can you please suggest how that would work out with Custom Button?

Comment: It's so simple just set the text in Label that you are owing right now.Place a custom button (UIButton) over Label & in the Button's action event just pass that LabelText & open it in web view. Do you want me provide the code for this??